# Rust: Initialize 2D Array

Tags: arrays, memory, multidimensional-array, rust, initialization

I have a struct, which contains the following 2D array:

```rust
board: [[Option<Rc<dyn Piece>>; SIZE]; SIZE]
```

Incidentally, this is representing a chess board, and Piece is a trait, so if there is a better way to store this data, I would be interested.

I am having difficulty initializing this array. The obvious solution, setting everything to None:

```rust
board: [[None; SIZE]; SIZE]
```

doesn't work because

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::rc::Rc<(dyn piece::Piece + 'static)>: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
  --> src/chessboard.rs:17:21
   |
17 |             board: [[None; SIZE]; SIZE]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `std::rc::Rc<(dyn piece::Piece + 'static)>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Copy` for `std::option::Option<std::rc::Rc<(dyn piece::Piece + 'static)>>`
   = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied
```

Some research led me to this github issue on the topic, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54542, where there seems to be some disagreement about the topic, though most solutions appear to use `MaybeUninit` and unsafe rust to create the array in memory, iterate over it to initialize it, then either `mem::transmute` or `into_inner` it into the regular array. Because I am not very familiar with unsafe rust or dealing with memory, I'd rather not use these solutions, and am not entirely certain how to adapt those solutions, which are for `[Vec<u8>; N]` to my use case.

I found another article on the subject, https://www.joshmcguigan.com/blog/array-initialization-rust/, which presents a crate with a macro, `arr!` which is supposed to be entirely safe. However, I am also not certain if this is the most idiomatic and clean solution. Having to install an entire crate for such a small thing seems excessive (though that may be my feelings from languages, as I don't know much about the best practices in Rust).

Which, if either, of these solutions should I use, and if it is the former, how should I adapt it to arrays of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [`ndarray`](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray):

```rust
use ndarray::Array;
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Piece: std::fmt::Debug {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {}

impl Piece for A {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B {}

impl Piece for B {}

fn main() {
    const SIZE: usize = 8;
    let a = Array::from_shape_fn((SIZE, SIZE), |i| {
        if (i.0 + i.1) % 2 == 0 {
            Some(Arc::new(A {}) as Arc<dyn Piece>)
        } else {
            Some(Arc::new(B {}) as Arc<dyn Piece>)
        }
    });

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

But that not very idiomatic in my opinion, I think you should prefer use an enum:

```rust
use ndarray::Array;
use std::sync::Arc;

trait Action {
    fn action(&self);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {}

impl Action for A {
    fn action(&self) {
        println!("Action of A");
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B {}

impl Action for B {
    fn action(&self) {
        println!("Action of B");
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Piece {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}

impl Action for Piece {
    fn action(&self) {
        match self {
            Piece::A(a) => a.action(),
            Piece::B(b) => b.action(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    const SIZE: usize = 8;
    let a = Array::from_shape_fn((SIZE, SIZE), |i| {
        if (i.0 + i.1) % 2 == 0 {
            Some(Arc::new(Piece::A(A {})))
        } else {
            Some(Arc::new(Piece::B(B {})))
        }
    });

    println!("{:?}", a);
    for piece in a.iter().flatten() {
        piece.action();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, an enum makes a lot of sense. I didn't realize that would work like that. The reason I didn't go for an `Rc<Option<dyn Piece>>` was because I was getting the "size not defined error", as you can see in this playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ce1c3cdb08f7f680806ad4137e44aa4 

However, with Piece being an enum, both forms appear to compile fine, so do you have any idea which is more efficient? I seem to recall that Option<Rc<T>> is optimized by storing None as zeros, and Some as any other pointer, though I'm not sure.

Comment: @RitobanRoyChowdhury I never use dyn trait nevermind, well the efficient question is a good one, I really don't know. https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/0.1.3/enum_dispatch/ claim to speed up 10x by using enum. Yes `Option<Rc<T>>` will same some byte. I don't know why but in my mind the purpose was to stock the board not only the piece. In that maybe you should only have a hashmap of piece left in the board. where key is a tupple of their coordinate and just remove `Option`. There is not a only way to implement a chess game :p